# What is the difference between "herbei" and "her"?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference between "herbei" and "her"? Is it right we say "herbei" is more formal?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/herbei ### https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/herbei ### https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/herbei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Herbei is the long-form of "her" and can be used as a synonym. You can say "Kommt alle her!" just as "Kommt alle herbei!". Herbei sounds a bit old-fashioned or formal though, I would expect it to be used in theater or so.

Answer (score 1):

The adverb of herbei is not very frequently used, it means "from there to here".

But of all occurrences I found on a quick glance, in more than 80% of the cases it was the separated particle of the verbs

- herbeiführen
- herbeilaufen
- herbeizitieren

Espcially *herbeiführen* has such a special meaning, that replacement by *herführen* is impossible.